# Angular 2 - [attr.selected] works but select nothing

Tags: html, angular

I have a simple problem but i don't find a solution

I have this select:

```
<select name="projectObjectUpdate" [ngFormControl]="_projectAmountForm.controls['projectObject']"
                                            class="form-control form-control-select2-field">
                                        <option *ngFor="let object of _projectObjectList" [ngValue]="object" [attr.selected]="object.id === _projectAmountForm.controls['projectObject'].value.id ? true : null">
                                            {{object.descriptions[_user.language]}}
                                        </option>
                                    </select>
```

[In the HTML code, good option is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FDDz.png)

[but nothing is selected on screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLNf7.png)

anyone knows the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also could just bind `ngModel` on your select element.

```
<select name="projectObjectUpdate" [ngModel]="_projectAmountForm.controls['projectObject'].value.id" [ngFormControl]="_projectAmountForm.controls['projectObject']"
        class="form-control form-control-select2-field" >
    <option *ngFor="let object of _projectObjectList" [ngValue]="object" >
        {{object.descriptions[_user.language]}}
    </option>
</select>
```

This will always select the `option` element with the same value as `_projectAmountForm.controls['projectObject'].value.id`

**EDIT:**

Sorry, yes `ngValue` was wrong! I meant `ngModel`. Corrected.

Comment: thanks, just you can't bind [ngValue] to select, you must bind [value] in the select and replace [ngValue] by [value] in the option and it works

Comment: @Uak Ups I indeed used the wrong attribute. Check my edit.
But yours works too of course

Answer (score -1):

Try binding to the [selected] attribute, like that:

```
<option *ngFor="let object of _projectObjectList" [ngValue]="object" [selected]="object.id === _projectAmountForm.controls['projectObject'].value.id">
```